# "The Evil One" in Sherlock Holmes series

Tags: arthur-conan-doyle, sherlock-holmes

Holmes makes a reference to an individual he referred to as the "Evil One" in "The Adventure Of Charles Augustus Milverton", though without explicitly naming him:

> ...He is as cunning as the Evil One.

Exactly who is the "Evil One", and what is his significance in the Sherlock Holmes series?

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was a moniker for someone specifically within the _Sherlock Holmes_ series. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To ensure that there is an answer, ["The Evil One" is a euphemism for the Devil](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/the_evil_one), likely under the superstitious idea that [speaking the name of a being might invoke or invite it](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2019/04/04/word-bear/), the same reason that the word "bear" ("the brown one") became popular, and the original Germanic word for the creature is now unknown.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that that is the etymology of the word “bear”! The entry in the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bear) is interesting.